# remove pic in quick setting grid

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, profiles

In the "quick settings" grid you get by pulling down the right-hand end of the notification bar, the top-left item is a photo. I'd like to edit or remove this photo, but when I tap it, it says "The contact doesn't exist."

How can I edit or remove this photo?

Comment: I am sorry, it is not clear about what you are talking about. To help, you have to throw in more information - put yourself in other's shoes and see how those not involved with your problem can understand your question. You wouldn't get answers if your question is not understandable.

Comment: ok Narayanan, i'll try to be more specific now on. as per this one, its resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go into the **People** or **Contacts** app. At the top of the list is a heading **Me** with a special item to **Set up my profile**. Click that item and it takes you to the "New contact" screen. On this screen, to the right of the "name" field, there's a little grey "contact icon" box. If you click that you can replace the photo with a picture from the Gallery or by taking a photo.

Comment: Why is this not taken from my address book like every other contact?

Comment: @endolith I thought I explained that it is, it's just a special "me" contact.

Answer (score 1):

The picture you are looking for is

/data/system/users/0/photo.png

just delete it to get rid of it.

God bless.